# Phonegap + обновление контента

Tags: phonegap, android

Парни, у меня в phonegap завернуто одно веб-приложение. Все работает, пользователи радуются.

Однако, иногда нужно менять контент, а именно пару цифр изменять в нескольких html страничках.

Как реализовать автоматическое обновление контента в приложении? Допустим, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, приложение проверяло наличие обновления на моем сайте. Или любым другим удобным способом.

В инете так и не нашел решения, на стэковерфлоу полно подобных вопросов, а толкового решения нет. Ну не обновлять же каждый раз приложение в маркете.

Спасибо.

Comment: Раз оно веб приложение, то кто мешает эти файлы подтягивать с интернета?

Comment: Если html у вас зашиты в приложении то ни как, так как режим работы с файлами из ресурсов онли рид. Можно создать дополнительную папку в директории сбросить все имеющиеся файлы в нее при первом запуске приложения, в преференсах хранить текущую версию базы, и при ее изменении заменять файлы пути к которым вы можете прописать создав небольшое апи для своего приложения!

Answer (score 2):

Я тоже сделал похожее приложение: меню и статические странички сделаны статическими файлами, использовал фреймворк materialize.css.
В самом простом варианте веб-страницу приложения можно поместить в статическую с помощью фрейма:

```
   <div class="tab active" id="index">
        <iframe class="iframe" src="http://yoursite.com">
            Ваш браузер не поддерживает плавающие фреймы!
        </iframe>
        <div id="offline" class="hidden">
            <div class="container">
                <p>Необходимо интернет соединение.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

В файл-ассет index.js в таком случае можно добавить проверку, есть ли соединение:

```
document.addEventListener("online", showOnline, false);
document.addEventListener("offline", showOffline, false);
function showOffline() {
    $(".iframe").hide();
    $("#offline").show(0);
}
function showOnline() {
    $(".iframe").show().attr('src', $('.iframe').attr('src'));;
    $("#offline").hide(0);
}
document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);

function onResume() {
    location.reload();
}
```

Пример выдран из моего приложения, надеюсь, все будет понятно.
Инициировать обновление "на-ходу" из сервера в любом случае потребует значительное усложнение кода и все равно потребует интернет-подлючение. Если хотите чтобы сервер инициировал обновление страницы в приложении, понадобится сокеты или лонг-пуллинг. Так что способ с фреймом самый бескровный, можно сказать.

Comment: Кстати, как вариант, можно сделать сервер, который по нужному запросу/адресу выдавал бы голые данные, например в виде JSON, получился бы что-то типа REST-сервер, данные оттуда можно было б подгружать с помощью AJAX, картинки хранить в виде ссылки на реальную картинку в интернете. Удобный способ, если динамический контент всегда имеет одну и ту же верстку, но если контент может менять верстку, придётся делать костыль с iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Обновляемы контент можно подгружать `XHR`'ом и хранить все это в `localstorage`